# Display clientside the HTML page that the server has returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**So,** I have a piece of PHP code which returns an HTML file as response.

The PHP code uses the `include` method to return the file.

On the clientside I use `AJAX`. When I type `console.log(data)` (in the **success** event), it just logs in the console the HTML code.

Now, I of course know, that `console.log` should not do anything, but what should I write in the `AJAX's` **success** event to display the page that the server has returned?

***Thank you in advance***

Answer (score 2):

You can take on div on a page were you want show ajax responce.
E.x

An in ajax sucess write following line

```
$('#ajax_re').html(data);
```

The data will be the response of ajax

Answer (score 0):

You do it by using the append function. In query
on success function of ajax add the code:

```
$('MAIN HTML BODY ID').append(resulthtmlstring);
```